# image in pdf file becomes invisible after adding digital signature

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I am using iTextSharp library for digital signature. In my PDF file having a QR code and once we applied signature the QR code became a gray color.

The figure (A) shows a original PDF and figure (B) shows the PDF file after digital signature.
following is the code to apply the signature. Please help me, why the QR code became gray color.

```
public void Sign(PDFSignatureAP sigAP, bool encrypt, PdfEncryption Enc)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.inputPDF);
    reader.RemoveUsageRights();
    PdfStamper st;
    if (this.myCert == null) //No signature just write meta-data and quit
    {
         st = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, 
                             FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write));
    }
    else
    {
        st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(this.outputPDF, FileMode.Create, 
                                        FileAccess.Write), '\0', null, sigAP.Multi);
    }
    if (encrypt && Enc != null) Enc.Encrypt(st);
    st.MoreInfo = this.metadata.getMetaData();
    st.XmpMetadata = this.metadata.getStreamedMetaData();
    if (this.myCert == null) //No signature just write meta-data and quit
    {
       st.Close();
       return;
    }
    var pass = new SecureString();
    char[] array = myCert.Password.ToCharArray();
    foreach (char ch in array)
    {
        pass.AppendChar(ch);
    }
    var privateKey = myCert.SCertificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    CspParameters cspParameters = new CspParameters(privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderType,
            privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.ProviderName,
            privateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName,
              new System.Security.AccessControl.CryptoKeySecurity(),
            pass);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaCsp;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myCert.Path))
        rsaCsp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParameters);
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;
    sap.Reason = sigAP.SigReason;
    sap.Contact = sigAP.SigContact;
    sap.Location = sigAP.SigLocation;
    if (sigAP.Visible)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = st.Reader.GetPageSize(sigAP.Page);
        sap.Image = sigAP.RawData == null ? null : 
        iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sigAP.RawData);
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sigAP.CustomText))
            sap.Layer2Text = sigAP.CustomText + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now;
        sap.Acro6Layers = false;
        sap.Layer4Text = PdfSignatureAppearance.questionMark;
        sap.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
        sap.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(sigAP.SigX, sigAP.SigY, sigAP.SigX + sigAP.SigW, sigAP.SigY + sigAP.SigH), sigAP.Page, "Signature");
    }
    IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(myCert.SCertificate, "SHA1");
    MakeSignature.SignDetached(sap, externalSignature, myCert.Chain, null, null,myCert.Tsc, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    st.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

**Figure A** (original)

[image: Figure A]

**Figure B** (after digital signature applied)
[image: Figure B]

[Link for Pdf files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13jBpFrSkeZ1qqnaWDhIN_niQcwVTbdji?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share the pdf before and after signing, not merely Screenshots thereof.

Comment: Dear I have added link for sample pdf files. I think in before sign pdf file, barcode form field is used.

Comment: Neither of the files that you provided links for have a QR code or a gray box as shown in the images above.

Comment: Funny, on my end both PDFs show the QR code. If I view them in Adobe Acrobat Reader, that is, version 2021.007.30092. Viewing them in Chrome indeed shows neither gray box nor QR code.

Comment: @mkl: I had opened the PDF files using MS Edge (which is based on Chrome). Other information seems to be missing when opened using Chrome/MS Edge. When opened using Firefox, the information is there but the text is partially cut off and the QR code shows as alphanumeric characters. When opened using Adobe Acrobat DC both documents seem to display correctly.

Comment: The PDF in question includes a hybrid AcroForm/XFA form. This causes differences in appearance between different viewers. The effect the OP observes, though, looks like being caused by an Acrobat version which is different from the one I used and which applies different algorithms in respect to validation of usage rights. Dr.AmreshNikam, can you confirm that? Please partake in the discussions here if you still are interested in the topic.

Comment: Thanks all of you. I have install latest version of Adobe Acrobat DC and it's working.